# Getting Rspec test fails on Hartls rails tutorial ch. 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, railstutorial.org

I'm getting these failures and I don't know where to look to solve the problem. I've searched this site and can't find others with my problem. According to the Hartl tutorial, all the tests should pass.

The failures:

```
  C:\Sites\rails_projects\sample_app>bundle exec rspec spec
Rack::File headers parameter replaces cache_control after Rack 1.5.
←[32m.←[0m←[32m.←[0m←[32m.←[0m←[32m.←[0m←[32m.←[0m←[32m.←[0m←[32m.←[0m←[32m.←[0m
←[32m.←[0m←[32m.←[0m←[32m.←[0m←[31mF←[0m←[31mF←[0m←[31mF←[0m←[31mF←[0m←[31mF←[0m
←[32m.←[0m←[32m.←[0m←[32m.←[0m←[32m.←[0m←[32m.←[0m←[32m.←[0m←[32m.←[0m←[32m.←[0m
←[32m.←[0m←[31mF←[0m←[31mF←[0m←[31mF←[0m←[32m.←[0m←[32m.←[0m

Failures:

  1) when email address is already taken
     ←[31mFailure/Error:←[0m ←[31muser_with_same_email = @user.dup←[0m
     ←[31mTypeError:←[0m
       ←[31mcan't dup NilClass←[0m
←[36m     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:104:in `dup'←[0m
←[36m     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:104:in `block (2 levels) in <top (require
d)>'←[0m

  2) when name is too long
     ←[31mFailure/Error:←[0m ←[31mbefore { @user.name = "a" * 51 }←[0m
     ←[31mNoMethodError:←[0m
       ←[31mundefined method `name=' for nil:NilClass←[0m
←[36m     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required
)>'←[0m

  3) when password is not present
     ←[31mFailure/Error:←[0m ←[31mbefore { @user.password = @user.password_confi
rmation = " " }←[0m
     ←[31mNoMethodError:←[0m
       ←[31mundefined method `password_confirmation=' for nil:NilClass←[0m
←[36m     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:55:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required
)>'←[0m

  4) when password confirmation is nil
     ←[31mFailure/Error:←[0m ←[31mbefore { @user.password_confirmation = nil }←[
0m
     ←[31mNoMethodError:←[0m
       ←[31mundefined method `password_confirmation=' for nil:NilClass←[0m
←[36m     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:65:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required
)>'←[0m

  5) when email format is valid should be valid
     ←[31mFailure/Error:←[0m ←[31m@user.email = valid_address←[0m
     ←[31mNoMethodError:←[0m
       ←[31mundefined method `email=' for nil:NilClass←[0m
←[36m     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:97:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required
)>'←[0m
←[36m     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:96:in `each'←[0m
←[36m     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:96:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required
)>'←[0m

  6) when password doesn't match confirmation
     ←[31mFailure/Error:←[0m ←[31mbefore {@user.password_confirmation = "mismatc
h" }←[0m
     ←[31mNoMethodError:←[0m
       ←[31mundefined method `password_confirmation=' for nil:NilClass←[0m
←[36m     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:60:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required
)>'←[0m

  7) when name is not present
     ←[31mFailure/Error:←[0m ←[31mbefore { @user.name = " " }←[0m
     ←[31mNoMethodError:←[0m
       ←[31mundefined method `name=' for nil:NilClass←[0m
←[36m     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:71:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required
)>'←[0m

  8) when email format is invalid should be invalid
     ←[31mFailure/Error:←[0m ←[31m@user.email = invalid_address←[0m
     ←[31mNoMethodError:←[0m
       ←[31mundefined method `email=' for nil:NilClass←[0m
←[36m     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:87:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required
)>'←[0m
←[36m     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:86:in `each'←[0m
←[36m     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:86:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required
)>'←[0m

Finished in 2.42 seconds
←[31m30 examples, 8 failures←[0m

Failed examples:

←[31mrspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:109←[0m ←[36m# when email address is alrea
dy taken ←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:77←[0m ←[36m# when name is too long ←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:56←[0m ←[36m# when password is not present
 ←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:66←[0m ←[36m# when password confirmation i
s nil ←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:94←[0m ←[36m# when email format is valid s
hould be valid←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:61←[0m ←[36m# when password doesn't match
confirmation ←[0m
←[31mrspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:72←[0m ←[36m# when name is not present ←[0
m
←[31mrspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:82←[0m ←[36m# when email format is invalid
 should be invalid←[0m
```

My user_spec.rb file:

```
    require 'spec_helper'

describe User do

  before do
    @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com",
      password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar")
  end

  subject { @user }

  it { should respond_to(:name) }
  it { should respond_to(:email) }
  it { should respond_to(:password_digest) }
  it { should respond_to(:password) }
  it { should respond_to(:password_confirmation) }
  it { should respond_to(:authenticate) }

  it { should be_valid }

  describe "with a password that's too short" do
    before { @user.password = @user.password_confirmation = "a" * 5 }
    it { should be_invalid }
  end

  describe "return value of authenticate method" do
    before { @user.save }
    let(:found_user) { User.find_by_email(@user.email) }

  describe "with valid password" do
      it { should == found_user.authenticate(@user.password) }
    end

  describe "with invalid password" do
      let(:user_for_invalid_password) { found_user.authenticate("invalid") }

      it { should_not == user_for_invalid_password }
      specify { user_for_invalid_password.should be_false }
    end
  end
end

  describe "when password is not present" do
    before { @user.password = @user.password_confirmation = " " }
    it {should_not be_valid}
  end

  describe "when password doesn't match confirmation" do
    before {@user.password_confirmation = "mismatch" }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "when password confirmation is nil" do
    before { @user.password_confirmation = nil }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end


  describe "when name is not present" do
    before { @user.name = " " }
    it { should_not be_valid } 
   end

  describe "when name is too long" do
    before { @user.name = "a" * 51 }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

    describe "when email format is invalid" do

    it "should be invalid" do

      addresses = %w[user@foo,com user_at_foo.org example.user@foo.
                     foo@bar_baz.com foo@bar+baz.com]
      addresses.each do |invalid_address|
        @user.email = invalid_address
        @user.should_not be_valid
      end      
    end
  end

  describe "when email format is valid" do
    it "should be valid" do
      addresses = %w[user@foo.COM A_US-ER@f.b.org frst.lst@foo.jp a+b@baz.cn]
      addresses.each do |valid_address|
        @user.email = valid_address
        @user.should be_valid
      end      
    end
  end
  describe "when email address is already taken" do
    before do
      user_with_same_email = @user.dup
      user_with_same_email.email = @user.email.upcase
      user_with_same_email.save
    end

        it { should_not be_valid}
    end
  end
```

User.rb file:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
  has_secure_password

  before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence:   true,
                    format:     { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true
end
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Potentially it could be that you seemed to have accidentally closed out your `describe User` block after `describe "with invalid password"` with two extra `end`s.

Currently:

```
describe User do

  # ...
  describe "with invalid password" do
      let(:user_for_invalid_password) { found_user.authenticate("invalid") }

      it { should_not == user_for_invalid_password }
      specify { user_for_invalid_password.should be_false }
    end
  end
end

# ...

end
```

should be:

```
describe User do

  # ...
  describe "with invalid password" do
    let(:user_for_invalid_password) { found_user.authenticate("invalid") }

    it { should_not == user_for_invalid_password }
    specify { user_for_invalid_password.should be_false }    
  end

  # ...
end
```

Also, check your indentation and number of `end`s towards the end of the file.

Comment: I think Paul is right, that's what I've spotted as a mistake as well.

Comment: Thanks Paul and @PericlesThedorou. I had to look at Hartls Github to figure out what I was missing in terms of syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The error messages are telling us @user is never being instantiated

Looks like you're missing the `:each` after the `before`

```
before do
    @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com",
      password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar")
end
```

should be:

```
before (:each) do
    @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com",
      password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar")
end
```

The @user object should now be made & the tests go green :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply but that didn't work. I still get the same errors. `:each` is not part of the tutorial so I don't think that's the problem here.